# Why is my shopping feed exporting the sale price wrong?

Tags: shopping, google-product-feeds

I am on Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 and I can't figure out why my shopping feed is exporting the wrong sale price. All of my attributes are mapped correctly and the sale price shows correctly on the product page but when I export my feed it's doing some sort of calculation and raising the price. I thought maybe it was tax but I don't why it would be automatically adding tax. I am including an image of the product page and the same product in my Google Merchant Center. You can see that the regular price is correct, but the sale price is higher. Any ideas what could be causing this?

We figured out that for some reason there is a tax rate of 7.975% being applied behind the scenes. I found this on a code in the product page:

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(
{
"productId":"21387",
"priceFormat":{
    "pattern":"$%s",
    "precision":2,
    "requiredPrecision":2,
    "decimalSymbol":".",
    "groupSymbol":",",
    "groupLength":3,
    "integerRequired":1
},
"includeTax":"false",
"showIncludeTax":false,
"showBothPrices":false,
"productPrice":65.99,
"productOldPrice":69.99,
"priceInclTax":65.99,
"priceExclTax":65.99,
"skipCalculate":1,
"defaultTax":7.975,
"currentTax":0,
"idSuffix":"_clone",
"oldPlusDisposition":0,
"plusDisposition":0,
"plusDispositionTax":0,
"oldMinusDisposition":0,
"minusDisposition":0,
"tierPrices":[

],
"tierPricesInclTax":[

]
}
);
```

Would it require a code modification to disable this or do we possibly just have a setting wrong?

[image: Product Page] [image: Merchanct Center]

Comment: The JS code on the product page looks like it won't include taxes in the price. Your feed configuration may include taxes - you should check, it should have it's own settings for that. What extension are you using?

Comment: Sounds like the wrong tax settings. Can you include your tax rules in the question?